# fully css change the image of a <img> without touching on src

Tags: css

Hi i have a img src="image" tag.

Is there a way to fully change that image via css?
I cant change the javascript or the html either.
I tried background-image but the original image stills the one that appear

i tried using backroung-image, opacity 0 and img::before tags.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: One cannot change the an image displayed by an `<img>` element with only CSS.

Comment: thanks @Wongjn for your kindness around stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you need **`content`** in the `img` in css to change your current image source with one attached on your css.

*This is current image.*

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tYLcxU6.jpg">
```

Now, using **content** in css, it will change the source of the image.

```css
img {
    content:url("https://i.imgur.com/TVApmhO.jpg");
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tYLcxU6.jpg">
```